# need to jump to the end of a fadein effect with an onclick event

Tags: jquery, click, fadein

This is a bit of a strange one, but I hope you guys can help.

I have a client that has requested a strange animation fade-in sequence with objects that fade in/out, but also wants a button that will supercede the animation and jump to the completed state instantly.

Currently, this is the javascript I'm using(jquery of course).

```
$("#finished-button" ).click(function() {
    $('#slide-1').fadeTo(1,.1);
    $('#slide-2').fadeIn(1);
    $("#slide-1" ).stop(); 
    $("#slide-2" ).stop();
    ;});
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#slide-1').delay(5000).fadeTo(5000,1).delay(11000).fadeTo(5000,.1);
    $('#slide-2').delay(21000).fadeIn(5000);   
;});
```

the div ID 'finished-button' being the button to jump to the finished state, but this isn't working.   What am I missing/what am I getting wrong with the syntax?  Thanks guys!

Comment: In your click handler, try putting the `.stop()` calls _before_ adding the new animations.

Comment: Check out [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) it will help you with the animation.

Comment: You can try [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) if you need the animation to simply jump to its' final state

Comment: Finish worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the `animation queue` first, then you can `show` those elements and set its final style properties using `.css()`.

Try,

```
$("#finished-button" ).click(function() {
    $('#slide-1').stop().show().css('opacity','0.1');
    $('#slide-2').stop().show.css('opacity','1');
});
```

Or as @user2191572 specified you could use,

```
$("#finished-button" ).click(function() {
    $('#slide-1,#slide-2').finish();
});
```

Comment: That kinda works, but I still have issues with the standard site animation, the original delays and fades set, which seem to run at the same time now.

Comment: @user2983416 what issues.? can you explain.?

Comment: sorry, I tried to past and it didnt' let me; the problem is the original fades and delays are still running.

Comment: the finish() command worked perfectly.  I'm marking as answered :)